# Kendo-ui combobox list not displayed on google maps fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

In our app we use google maps and we have embedded forms with some kendo combobox, numeric textbox, buttons...

When I open the map fullscreen mode, the combobox list is not displayed.
This only happens with Firefox and Internet Explorer. Chrome is OK

Here is a dojo.telerik which shows the problem :
http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/@tdf/eZOgA/5

> Problem in fullscreen mode only

Thanks in advance

Comment: tested on all of the 3 mentioned browsers, they seem to be working fine, when clicking on the down arrow to show the list.

Comment: @randomguy04 In fullscreen mode of google maps too ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the Google Maps canvas are rendered on top of the dropdown. You can use the Client API of the Kendo Combobox and the appendTo method in particular. Hence, you can append the dropdown to a parent element and properly render it:

```
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-popup.appendTo

http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/uKUWeg/5
```